# How to identify used columns of a view in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

There is a view ***View1*** in Database ***D1*** with columns **Column1**, **Column2**, **Column3**

The view ***View1*** is consumed in another Database ***D2*** within a stored procedure **PROC1**
Only **Column2** is used in the stored procedure **PROC1** while other columns are not used

The view ***View1*** is consumed in another Database ***D3*** within a stored procedure **PROC2**
**Column1** and **Column2** are used in the stored procedure **PROC2** while other column is not used

How do we identify which column of the ***View1*** are consumed in the stored procedure **PROC1**, **PROC2** by using a query.

I have almost 100 views which are consumed in multiple databases and I need to know which all columns are consumed by stored procedures in their respective database.

Comment: Are the databases on the same SQL Server instance? I am unaware of any tool that does this accurately. If this were my issue, I would be string searching for the view (hopefully a unique name) in the extracted objects and manually looking to see what the scope is.

Comment: You can query system tables for SP text for your view name to find what views there are.  You can add an AND statement for the column names as well, but if the column names and/or table name are not unique across your DB you may get results returned that are not accurate but it could narrow it down

Comment: Good luck. This is actually far more difficult than you can imagine. What happens if your procedure uses a function that references the same or other views? What if there is dynamic sql involved? What if (god forbid) you have nested views? And then trying to decipher the reference across databases??? There is one and only one way to be sure this is accurate. Roll up your sleeves and chase every line of code to the end and document this manually. There are just way too many possible misses doing this with a query.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute:

exec sp_depends 'name of view'

this will return all the objects (include procedures) that refer to the view. You would have to examine the named proc itself to determine which columns are used in the procedure.

Comment: This is an awesome start for sure. It will miss things like functions in the procedure that also reference the view or dynamic sql. And since this only works within a single database so it will not find references in the other databases.

Answer (score 0):

Within a DB you can identify where column1 is used in stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @Search VARCHAR(255)
SET @Search = 'Column1'

SELECT DISTINCT
    o.name AS Object_Name, o.type_desc
FROM 
    sys.sql_modules m 
INNER JOIN 
    sys.objects o ON m.object_id = o.object_id
WHERE 
    m.definition LIKE '%' + @Search + '%' 
    AND type_desc = 'SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE'
ORDER BY 
    2, 1
```

If you're looking in a different DB, then include `[differentDBname].sys.sql_modules`